# Excel: custom format of a number to appear like that "667,379.72"

Tags: excel

I want to create a custom format in excel to let that number:

"667,379.72" be displayed like that "€ 667,379.72"

I tried so many formats (such as '€ ###_,##0.00'). However, It did not displayed as wanted and caused a problem when I used it in further calculation.

Here what I did: I specified the cell format to number, then I wrote exactly the number that way " 667,379.72" and finally I changed the cell format to custom and I wrote this "€ ###_,##0.00". This is the displayed result:
[Excel format number problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inckA.png)

'#value!' is displayed when I tried to sum up the two numbers.

What is the right format to use?

Comment: How did it display? What trouble did it cause in calculations? Could the problem be that it is a text string and not a number?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  I edited the post, please take a look to see the result that I had when I tried that cell format.

Comment: What country are your windows regional settings?  What value is returned if you enter a formula `=ISTEXT(cell_ref)` where `cell_ref` refers to the cell containing the `667,379.72`

Comment: Also, try entering the value without any separators at all. eg `=66737972/10`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the country is France. ISTEXT() function returned 'TRUE' although I did not specify the format as general.

Comment: I tried entering the number like that: '=66737972/10' and here what is displayed: 6 673 897,200 and it gave the wrong math result when I added it to 100,000.

Comment: When you are entering the number, you need to use the same separators as your country. In other words, you need to enter it with the space and comma as the thousands and decimal separator. If you must enter it with the comma and dot, then you will need to use VBA. Excel parses entries according to your Windows regional settings, not according to the format of the cell.

Comment: Do your tests in a brand new workbook with no formatting (enter a number in cell A1 - then format it). If it doesn't work as expected tell us EXACTLY what you did every step of the way. You obviously have something weird either with your numbers or formatting - it is very hard to answer questions like this because for 99.9999% of the people in the world you put a number in a cell and apply a format and everything works as expected. You have something else affecting this cell that we don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a built in Euro currency format that certainly works for a case like this:

[image]

Comment: I edited the post, please take a look to see the result that I had when I tried that cell format. ( I tried also what you said, but it still the same problem and the result is the same as the image I added to the post.)